# IllegalStateException BlackBerry

Tags: exception, blackberry, java-me, timer, calendar

```
public class show extends MainScreen {
    private String date1;
    private long date1l;
    private long date2l;
    private LabelField curDate = new LabelField();
    private LabelField toDate = new LabelField();
    private LabelField diffe = new LabelField();
    // private LabelField info;
    // private LabelField empty;
    // private InvokeBrowserHyperlinkField hello;

    ButtonField activate = null;
    ButtonField disactivate = null;
    Timer timer;
    Timer timer2;

    public String date1s[];
    int d, m, y;
    int x = 1;
    String day, hour, minute;
    Date date = new Date();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy HH mm");

    public show() {
        add(curDate);
        add(toDate);
        add(new SeparatorField());
        add(diffe);

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTick(), 0, 1000);
    }

    private class TimerTick extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            if (x != 0) {
                date1l = date.getTime();

                try {
                    date1 = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+7:00"));
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);

                date2l = cal.getTime().getTime();

                date1s = StringUtilities.stringToWords(date1);
                d = Integer.parseInt(date1s[0]);
                m = Integer.parseInt(date1s[1]);
                y = Integer.parseInt(date1s[2]);
                display();
            } else {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    }

    public void display() {
        String monw = convertToWords(m);
        curDate.setText("Current Date = " + d + " " + monw + " " + y + " "
                + date1s[3] + ":" + date1s[4]);
        toDate.setText("To Date = 1 February 2012 00:00");

        long diffms = date2l - date1l;
        long ds = diffms / 1000;
        long dm = ds / 60;
        long dh = dm / 60;
        long dd = dh / 24;

        long q = dd;
        long h = (ds - (dd * 24 * 60 * 60)) / (60 * 60);
        long m = (ds - (dh * 60 * 60)) / 60;

        diffe.setText("Remaining Time : \n" + Long.toString(q) + " day(s) "
                + Long.toString(h) + " hour(s) " + Long.toString(m)
                + " minute(s)");

        day = Long.toString(q);
        hour = Long.toString(h);
        minute = Long.toString(m);

        showMessage();
    }

    /*
     * private void link() { empty = new LabelField("\n\n"); add(empty); hello =
     * new InvokeBrowserHyperlinkField("Click here",
     * "http://indri.dedicated-it.com/wordpress/?page_id=17"); add(hello); info
     * = new LabelField("\n\nPress menu then choose \"Get Link\" to access");
     * add(info); }
     */

    void showMessage() {
        activate = new ButtonField("Activate", FIELD_HCENTER) {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int action, int time) {
                if (activate.isFocus()) {
                    Dialog.alert("Started!!");
                    Start();
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        add(activate);

        disactivate = new ButtonField("Disactivate", FIELD_HCENTER) {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int action, int time) {
                if (disactivate.isFocus()) {
                    Dialog.alert("Stopped!!");
                    timer2.cancel();
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        add(disactivate);

        /*
         * UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine(); Screen screen = new
         * Dialog(Dialog.D_OK, data, Dialog.OK,
         * Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.EXCLAMATION),
         * Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL); ui.queueStatus(screen, 1, true);
         */
    }

    public void Start() {
        timer2 = new Timer();

        timer2.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTick2(), 0, 6000);
    }

    private class TimerTick2 extends TimerTask {

        public void run() {

            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) {
                        UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();
                        Screen screen = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK, "Hello!",
                                Dialog.OK,
                                Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.EXCLAMATION),
                                Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
                        ui.pushGlobalScreen(screen, 1, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);
                    }
                }

            });

        }
    }

    private String convertToWords(int m) {
        String w = "";
        switch (m) {
        case 1:
            w = "January";
            break;
        case 2:
            w = "February";
            break;
        case 3:
            w = "March";
            break;
        case 4:
            w = "April";
            break;
        case 5:
            w = "May";
            break;
        case 6:
            w = "June";
            break;
        case 7:
            w = "July";
            break;
        case 8:
            w = "August";
            break;
        case 9:
            w = "September";
            break;
        case 10:
            w = "October";
            break;
        case 11:
            w = "November";
            break;
        case 12:
            w = "December";
            break;
        }
        return w;
    }

    public boolean onClose() {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestBackground();
        return true;
    }
}
```

What actually is JVM 104 IllegalStateException? This program is a countdown program, which counts the remaining time from today until February 1st. Also, I implement a timer function that appears even if the application is closed. Can u please help me locate the problem? Thank you

Comment: can u check at which line you are getting this exception...

Comment: Do you want other than this code; I had like.. I am taking two different dates and start the countdown by taking their difference(in seconds);

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace of the exception, and tell us at which line of this code snippet it occurs. And please learn the Java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: The JVM 104 error is a broad catch-all for many things that can go wrong from which the JVM can not easily recover. IlleagalStateException is trown when a program does something for which the appropriate state is not set. I haven't gone through your code, but a quick glace would make me guess you are trying to modify the display from a non-event thread without holding the event lock. Knowing the line where the exceptionis thrown (as other have said) would help find the problem.

Comment: @alishaik786 yeah I could use that

Comment: @alishaik786 Yeah u can just post here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7740/richard) said, you are trying to update LabelField from another thread. Try the following code snippet:

```
synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) {
    labelField.setText();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code and change according to your requirement;

```
public class FirstScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{   
LabelField label;
Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask;
int secs=0;
long start,end;
String startDate="2012-01-28",endDate="2012-01-29"; 
ButtonField startCountDown;
public FirstScreen() 
{
    createGUI();        
}

private void createGUI() 
{       
    startCountDown=new ButtonField("Start");
    startCountDown.setChangeListener(this);
    add(startCountDown);
}

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
{
    if(field==startCountDown)
    {
        start=System.currentTimeMillis();
         //this is the current time milliseconds; if you want to use two different dates
        //except current date then put the comment for "start=System.currentTimeMillis();" and 
       //remove comments for the below two lines;
       //Date date=new Date(HttpDateParser.parse(startDate));
       //start=date.getTime();

        Date date=new Date(HttpDateParser.parse(endDate));
        end=date.getTime();
        int difference=(int)(end-start);
        difference=difference/1000;//Now converted to seconds;
        secs=difference;
        Status.show("Seconds: "+secs,100);
        callTheTimer();         
    }
}

public void callTheTimer()
{   
    label=new LabelField();
    add(label);
    timer=new Timer();
    timerTask=new TimerTask() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) 
            {
                if(secs!=0)
                {
                    label.setText(""+(secs--)+" secs");                 
                }
                else
                {   
                    timer.cancel();                     
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            label.setText("");
                            Dialog.alert("Times Up");                                                              
                        }           
                    });                     
                }
            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
}
protected boolean onSavePrompt() 
{
    return true;
}
public boolean onMenu(int instance) 
{
    return true;
}
public boolean onClose() 
{
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestBackground();
    return super.onClose();
}
}
```

In this code I am taking taking two different dates and start the countdown by taking their difference(in seconds); See the comments in the code;

Comment: I actually need the one that can update itself without having the application closed. That's why I used RealTimeClockListener. But I keep on getting error when using that.

Comment: use UiApplication.getUiApplication.requestBackground(); in "onClose" Method;

Comment: Using that will cause the app keeps on running I know, but it will make the clock freeze because without RealTimeClockListener, the clock will not refresh itself.